# Run tests while browsers are playing video

Tags: selenium-webdriver, grid

In order to test my application, I need to have a few browsers playing video, and then, while those browsers are playing, run the tests.

I'm using Selenium Grid deployed in Docker Swarm, and pytest.

How can I achieve this? Because the only idea that comes to my mind is to use async calls for the browsers, and then run the tests sequentially (or even parallel, as they are just queries to an API), but I'm not sure that's the good approach.

Comment: Can't you simply open a browser with multiple tabs open and open YouTube in one of those tabs?